# How can I limit the width of the v-data-table column?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to limit the width of the Video title column in my headers by using the width: '30%' property. However, even with this setting, the column width exceeds the specified percentage. I also tried using maxWidth: '30%', but it didn't resolve the issue. How can I do it?

```
<v-data-table
  :loading="loading"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="rankedItems"
  :server-items-length="itemCount"
  :disable-sort="true"
  :hide-default-footer="true"
  class="elevation-1"
>
  <template #item.rank="{ item }">
    #{{ item.rank }}
  </template>
  <template #item.user="{ item }">
    <user-chip
      :uid="item.uid"
      :nickname="item.name"
      :avatar-url="item.avatar"
    />
  </template>
  <template #item.value="{ item }">
    {{ $n(item.value) }}
  </template>
  <template #item.gv="{ item }">
    {{ $n(item.gv) }}
  </template>
  <template #item.title="{ item }">
    <v-chip
      :to="{ name: 'videoPlay', params: { id: item.vid } }"
      target="_blank"
      outlined
      label
    >
      {{ item.title }}
    </v-chip>
  </template>
</v-data-table>

computed: {
  headers () {
    return [
      { text: '', value: 'rank', width: '20%' },
      { text: 'Name', value: 'user', width: '30%' },
      { text: 'Video title', value: 'title', width: '30%' },
      { text: 'value', value: 'gv', width: '20%' },
    ]
  },
},
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one solution you could use in css is

```
videoTitleStyle{
    maxWidth: 30%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

this is one way to hide the text that extends the `maxWidht`